# Trying to write XDP for redirecting packets in veth inside kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, networking, linux-kernel, xdp-bpf

I want to use XDP for redirecting packets sent from pint-1 to ping-3 pod redirect to ping-2 pod inside Kubernetes, and testing this using ICMP(ping) inside the pod.

What I was expecting is that I can receivee modified ping packet in ping-2 pod.

I used hard-coded IP and MAC address in the code, and used `return bpf_redirect()`、`XDP_TX`、`XDP_REDIRECT`, but none of them worked.

I used perf to trace the XDP event and I got

```
➜  ebpf sudo perf trace --event 'xdp:*'
# bpf_redirect(ifindex2, 0)
     0.000 ping/936614 xdp:xdp_redirect_err:prog_id=1426 action=REDIRECT ifindex=66 to_ifindex=67 err=-6
# XDP_TX
 15562.756 ping/936800 xdp:xdp_bulk_tx:ifindex=66 action=TX sent=0 drops=1 err=-6
# XDP_REDIRECT
 27807.646 ping/936940 xdp:xdp_redirect_err:prog_id=1428 action=REDIRECT ifindex=66 to_ifindex=0 err=-22
```

My ENV setup is in fowlling

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04(VM on Proxmox VE)
Kernel: 5.4.0-144-generic
Kubernetes: 1.23.17
CNI: flannel
clang: Ubuntu clang version 11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1
```

Pod YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ping-1-privileged
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ping-1-privileged
    image: ubuntu20.04
    command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ping-2-privileged
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ping-2-privileged
    image: ubuntu20.04
    command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ping-3-privileged
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ping-3-privileged
    image: ubuntu20.04
    command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

and my code

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>  // XDP_PASS, ...
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/icmp.h>
// #include <netinet/in.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>  // SEC, bpf_printk
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/*
ping-1                                      1/1     Running   0          16d    10.244.0.59   ubuntu-pve   <none>           <none>
ping-1-privileged                           1/1     Running   0          13m    10.244.0.64   ubuntu-pve   <none>           <none>
ping-2                                      1/1     Running   0          16d    10.244.0.60   ubuntu-pve   <none>           <none>
ping-2-privileged                           1/1     Running   0          13m    10.244.0.63   ubuntu-pve   <none>           <none>
ping-3                                      1/1     Running   0          16d    10.244.0.61   ubuntu-pve   <none>           <none>
ping-3-privileged                           1/1     Running   0          13m    10.244.0.62   ubuntu-pve   <none>           
*/

const unsigned char ping_1_mac[6] = {0x92, 0xd3, 0x27, 0xf3, 0x2b, 0x11};
const unsigned char ping_2_mac[6] = {0xba, 0x0f, 0x32, 0xb0, 0xc6, 0x20};
const unsigned char ping_3_mac[6] = {0x72, 0x2f, 0xc1, 0xcd, 0x63, 0xa9};

const __u32 ping_1_ip = 10 | (244 << 8) | (0 << 16) | (64 << 24);
const __u32 ping_2_ip = 10 | (244 << 8) | (0 << 16) | (63 << 24);
const __be32 ping_3_ip = 10 | (244 << 8) | (0 << 16) | (62 << 24);

SEC("xdpprogram")
int myxdpprogram(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    void * data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void * data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;

    struct ethhdr * eth = data;
    if ((void*)eth + sizeof(*eth) <= data_end) {  // MAC ram size check
        struct iphdr * ip = data + sizeof(*eth);
        if ((void*)ip + sizeof(*ip) <= data_end) {  // IP ram size check
            if (ip->protocol == 1) { // check ICMP protocol
                struct icmphdr * icmp = data + sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip);
                if ((void*)icmp + sizeof(*icmp) <= data_end) {  // ICMP ram size check
                    __u32 ifindex2 = 67;
                    bpf_printk("[Debug] ifindex2: %d\n", ifindex2);
                    bpf_printk("==========\n");

                    _Bool check_result = 1;
                    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) { // check mac
                        if (eth->h_source[i] != ping_3_mac[i] || eth->h_dest[i] != ping_1_mac[i]) {
                            bpf_printk("MAC ERROR\n");
                            check_result = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ip->saddr != ping_3_ip || ip->daddr != ping_1_ip) { // check ip
                        bpf_printk("IP ERROR\n");
                        check_result = 0;
                    }

                    if (check_result == 1) {
                        bpf_printk("[ Start of REWRITE! ]\n");

                        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                            bpf_printk("[PRI][MAC][SRC][ORI] %x\n", eth->h_source[i]);
                        }
                        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                            bpf_printk("[PRI][MAC][DEST][ORI] %x\n", eth->h_dest[i]);
                        }

                        bpf_printk("  ---  ETH ADDR CHANGED! --- \n");
                        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                            eth->h_dest[i] = ping_2_mac[i];
                        }
                        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                            bpf_printk("[PRI][MAC][SRC][MDF] %x\n", eth->h_source[i]);
                        }
                        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                            bpf_printk("[PRI][MAC][DEST][MDF] %x\n", eth->h_dest[i]);
                        }
                            bpf_printk("  ------------  Dividers ------------ \n");
                        __u8 sipv4_0 = ip->saddr & 0xFF;
                        __u8 sipv4_1 = (ip->saddr >> 8) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 sipv4_2 = (ip->saddr >> 16) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 sipv4_3 = (ip->saddr >> 24) & 0xFF;
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][ORI][0]: %d\n", sipv4_0);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][ORI][0]: %d\n", sipv4_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][ORI][0]: %d\n", sipv4_2);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][ORI][0]: %d\n", sipv4_3);
                        __u8 dipv4_0 = ip->daddr & 0xFF;
                        __u8 dipv4_1 = (ip->daddr >> 8) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 dipv4_2 = (ip->daddr >> 16) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 dipv4_3 = (ip->daddr >> 24) & 0xFF;
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][ORI][0]: %d\n", dipv4_0);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][ORI][1]: %d\n", dipv4_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][ORI][2]: %d\n", dipv4_2);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][ORI][3]: %d\n", dipv4_3);
                        bpf_printk("  ---  IP SRC ADDR CHANGED! --- \n");
                        ip->saddr = ping_2_ip;
                        ip->daddr = ping_2_ip;
                        __u8 sipv4_0_1 = ip->saddr & 0xFF;
                        __u8 sipv4_1_1 = (ip->saddr >> 8) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 sipv4_2_1 = (ip->saddr >> 16) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 sipv4_3_1 = (ip->saddr >> 24) & 0xFF;
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][MDF][0]: %d\n", sipv4_0_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][MDF][0]: %d\n", sipv4_1_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][MDF][0]: %d\n", sipv4_2_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][SRC][MDF][0]: %d\n", sipv4_3_1);
                        __u8 dipv4_0_1 = ip->daddr & 0xFF;
                        __u8 dipv4_1_1 = (ip->daddr >> 8) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 dipv4_2_1 = (ip->daddr >> 16) & 0xFF;
                        __u8 dipv4_3_1 = (ip->daddr >> 24) & 0xFF;
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][MDF][0]: %d\n", dipv4_0_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][MDF][1]: %d\n", dipv4_1_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][MDF][2]: %d\n", dipv4_2_1);
                        bpf_printk("[PRI][IP][DST][MDF][3]: %d\n", dipv4_3_1);
                        bpf_printk("[ End of REWRITE! ]\n");

                        // return bpf_redirect(ifindex2, 0);
                        // return XDP_TX;
                        return XDP_REDIRECT;
                    
                    }
                    bpf_printk("ping-3\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL v2";
```

pod veth

```
➜  ebpf bash getpodveth.sh ping-1-privileged ping-2-privileged ping-3-privileged
Pod: ping-1-privileged
PodName: ping-1-privileged
ContainerID: "6560f8dff79d4c7473a33df510e630f10967229fb7363c493cc23a9898c93e4f"
ContainerPID: "414426"
IfNum: "68"
VethName: "veth7443cccc"

Pod: ping-2-privileged
PodName: ping-2-privileged
ContainerID: "7731cb692c775a3c81e264880da98016b5041e2edb68013f3c5906a6332b0044"
ContainerPID: "414323"
IfNum: "67"
VethName: "vethf362cb52"

Pod: ping-3-privileged
PodName: ping-3-privileged
ContainerID: "4868a00c9ffcb3bceb2aa9b8c6994b924eb55e2b0155ea74c2554d3f1fc55616"
ContainerPID: "414271"
IfNum: "66"
VethName: "veth12d73784"
```

How i set XDP

```
clang -target bpf -c ping3-privileged.c -o ping3-privileged.o -O2 && \
sudo ip link set dev veth12d73784 xdp off && \
sudo ip link set dev veth12d73784 xdp obj ping3-privileged.o sec xdpprogram && \
ip a | grep veth12d73784 | grep xdp && \
kubectl exec -it ping-1-privileged -- ping -c 1 10.244.0.62
```

Can anyone point out what I was wrong or missing?

I am expecting to have icmp packet when using tcpdump capturing veth of pod ping-2.

Comment: I don't see any code to update the IP checksum. Is that expected?

Comment: Also, why use XDP and not tc? BPF programs attached to the tc layer have access to many more helpers that could help with checksum computation for example.

Comment: I am trying to implement LB using XDP into virtual 5G network system(for research purpose), so performance is the 1st priority for me, that  is why I wanted to use XDP in native mode.

I have not implement checksum part of the code yet, so I was expecting I can receive packet using tcpdump(since it calls libbpf under the hood, which works in driver stack) and saw packet droped by Kernel(Network stack).

Comment: Using XDP vs. tc is unlikely to make a difference in terms of performance for the veth driver. The skb objects are already allocated at that point anyway. That's why production software like Cilium doesn't use XDP on its veth devices.